# How to add points to scatter3d?

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to plot two sets of points in the same 3D scatterplot using interactive "rgl" package for R

this is the data:

```
> head(tsne_train)
           X1         X2          X3
2   18.940912 -46.761145 -56.1818708
4   17.768953  68.678871   0.8070582
6   -2.440751 -53.021051  55.0437596
7   44.740812  -2.347877 -54.1501468
8  -87.924687  15.354890 -30.1806330
12  21.991465  38.406572 -33.0551010`

> head(tsne_test)
          X1         X2          X3
1   1.585156  71.568255    7.438958
3  62.204021  -3.817038  -37.609328
5   5.422276 -21.855152   66.865478
9  21.223133 -29.763255 -107.832779
10  9.037427 -62.816717   65.560664
11 24.775047 -51.820532   57.106795
```

this is what I tried so far:

```
scatter3d( x=tsne_train[,1],y=tsne_train[,2],z=tsne_train[,3],
          groups = train$Result,
          surface=F, grid = T, ellipsoid = FALSE,sphere.size = 1.5,
          surface.col = c("red", "orange", "green"),fogtype="none",
          axis.col=c("black","black","black"))
```

produces:
   [image]

and

```
scatter3d(x=tsne_test[,1],y=tsne_test[,2],z=tsne_test[,3], groups = test$Result,
                surface=F, grid = T, ellipsoid = FALSE,sphere.size = 1.5,
                col = c("purple", "blue", "cyan"), fogtype="none",
                axis.col=c("black","black","black"))
```

produces:
   [image]

I want all the points in one scatterplot but preserving the color grouping (6 colors in total). Kind of like overlaying plot 2 over plot 1

Using spheres3d to add more points to a plot leads to this mess:

```
spheres3d(x=tsne_test[,1],y=tsne_test[,2],z=tsne_test[,3],
         surface=F, grid = T,
         col = c("purple", "blue", "cyan"), sphere.size = 3,
         axis.col=c("black","black","black"))
```

[image]

this does not preserve the green/red/orange points from plot #1, the axes aren't visible and the position of the points looks off since plot #2 looks nothing like it. Maybe I am just using spheres3d wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _Dumitrescu Calin_! You may want to ensure yourself, that you share all necessary data (e.g. `train`) and state all `library` calls (e.g. `car`)to enable us to reproduce your code.

Comment: `scatter3d` is not an `rgl` function.  There's a function by that name in the `car` package.  It rescales points before it plots them, so you'll need to figure out how to do the same rescaling to add your points.

Comment: It appears the rescaling is simply `(x - minx)/(maxx - minx)` (and similarly for `y` and `z`).  You should be able to do the same if you use the min and max from the first plot to transform the values in the `spheres3d` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code based on my suggestions.  We don't have your real data, so I've used the data that you gave, with random values for groups.

```
tsne_train <- read.table(textConnection(
"           X1         X2          X3
2   18.940912 -46.761145 -56.1818708
4   17.768953  68.678871   0.8070582
6   -2.440751 -53.021051  55.0437596
7   44.740812  -2.347877 -54.1501468
8  -87.924687  15.354890 -30.1806330
12  21.991465  38.406572 -33.0551010"
), header=TRUE)
trainGroup <- factor(sample(1:3, 6, replace=TRUE))

tsne_test <- read.table(textConnection(
"          X1         X2          X3
1   1.585156  71.568255    7.438958
3  62.204021  -3.817038  -37.609328
5   5.422276 -21.855152   66.865478
9  21.223133 -29.763255 -107.832779
10  9.037427 -62.816717   65.560664
11 24.775047 -51.820532   57.106795"
), header=TRUE)
testGroup <- factor(sample(1:3, 6, replace=TRUE))

scatter3d(x = tsne_train[,1],
          y = tsne_train[,2],
          z = tsne_train[,3],
          groups = trainGroup,
          surface=FALSE, 
          grid = TRUE, 
          ellipsoid = FALSE,
          sphere.size = 1.5,
          surface.col = c("red",  "orange", "green"),
          fogtype = "none",
          axis.col = c("black","black","black"))
spheres3d(x = (tsne_test[,1]-min(tsne_train[,1]))/
              (max(tsne_train[,1]) - min(tsne_train[,1])),
          y = (tsne_test[,2]-min(tsne_train[,2]))/
              (max(tsne_train[,2]) - min(tsne_train[,2])),
          z = (tsne_test[,3]-min(tsne_train[,3]))/
              (max(tsne_train[,3]) - min(tsne_train[,3])),
          col = c("purple", "blue", "cyan")[testGroup], 
          radius = 0.1)
```

Here's what the plot looks like:

[image: screenshot]

This would all be easier if you didn't use the `scatter3d` function, you stuck with `rgl` functions.  For example,

```
plot3d( x = tsne_train,
            col = c("red", "orange", "green")\[trainGroup\], 
            type="s")
spheres3d(x = tsne_test,
          col = c("purple", "blue", "cyan")\[testGroup\], 
          radius = 3)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: screenshot]